# finding documents in mongodb by array for one field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to run a query to find all the documents that contain an array of phone numbers:

for example:

```
var mobileArray = ["07958485374","07958485375", "07958485378"];
```

an example document would be:

```
{
  phone_number: 07958483297,
  brand: "Mercedes",
  model: "S 350 L",
  year: 2007,
  price: 9500,
  description: "Full options - Automatic transmission - Gulf import - Excellent condition - V6 - Beig leather seats - Screen - Sunroof - CD - DVD - Telephone - Navigation - Xenon - Finger print - Bluetooth - Memory - Cruise control - Sensor - Wood - Clause examination - ",
  images_length: 4,
  _id: ObjectId("53a844d26d437e394844f0a3"),
  date: ISODate("2014-06-23T15:16:34.233Z"),
  __v: 0
}
```

So Im trying to run a query to find all documents that contains any of these elements in the array, I know I can probably run a for loop, but i would rather try do it in one query.

Im using mongoose node module to query my results.

for example:

```
 Car.find().where({"phone_number": "0795483297"}).limit(10).exec(function(err, docs) {
       res.send(docs);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "$in" operator:

> **$in**
>
> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field
>   equals any value in the specified array.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Using your example this should work for you:

```
Car.find({"phone_number": 
            { $in: ['0795483297', '07958485375', '07958485378']}
          }).limit(10).exec(function(err, docs) {
       res.send(docs);
  });
```